# Struggling With Instructor Tutorial

Tags: c#

I had an assignment that required me to request an array size from the user and then request numbers to fill the array.  The program was to print only the unique numbers for each loop.  It also would notify the user if the number they entered was a duplicate.  I have completed this and it worked as it should.  The instructor then posted a tutorial video on how it could/should have been written.  That code is quite different from mine and I tried to rewrite it to understand her logic.  I could not get it to work as the tutorial showed and I am not understanding some of the things she included.  Can someone look at this and help me understand what she is trying to do and if it works as written?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DuplicateHandsOn
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //create an array of type int
            int[] aList;

            //create a counter to keep track of how many numbers have been entered
            int counter = 0;

            //create a boolean flag to let us know whether the number can be added or not
            bool isDuplicate = false;

            //ask the user how many numbers they will be entering
            Console.WriteLine("How many numbers will you enter?");
            int arraySize = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            //initialize the array with that amount
            aList = new int[arraySize];

            while (counter < arraySize)
            {
                //prompt the user for the first number
                Console.Write("Enter Number: ");
                int num1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                //check if the number is between 10 and 100
                if (num1 >= 10 || num1 <= 100)
                {
                    //check if this number exists in the array
                    for (int i = 0; i < aList.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (aList[i] == num1)
                        {
                            //this number exists in the list
                            Console.WriteLine("{0} has already been entered", aList[i]);
                            isDuplicate = true;
                        }
                    }

                    if (isDuplicate)
                    {
                        //put the number into the array
                        aList[counter] = num1;
                    }

                    //print the array
                    for (int j = 0; j < aList.Length; j++)
                    {
                        //exclude zeros
                        if (aList[j] == 0)
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(aList[j]);
                        }
                    }

                    //increment the counter
                    counter++;

                    //reset the flag
                    isDuplicate = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Numbers should be between 10 and 100");
                }
            }

            #if DEBUG
            Console.ReadKey();
            #endif

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It didn't work for me using the CSC.exe C# compiler in .NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three bugs in the code, and lots of style issues I'd have with it, but the bugs are easy to point out.  I've added `// FIX` comments to show what I changed, hopefully it makes sense.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace DuplicateHandsOn
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //create an array of type int
            int[] aList;

            //create a counter to keep track of how many numbers have been entered
            int counter = 0;

            //create a boolean flag to let us know whether the number can be added or not
            bool isDuplicate = false;

            //ask the user how many numbers they will be entering
            Console.WriteLine("How many numbers will you enter?");
            int arraySize = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            //initialize the array with that amount
            aList = new int[arraySize];

            while (counter < arraySize)
            {
                //prompt the user for the first number
                Console.Write("Enter Number: ");
                int num1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                // FIX: This should be && instead of || to test if
                // both of these conditions are true to match
                // the comment
                //check if the number is between 10 and 100
                if (num1 >= 10 && num1 <= 100)
                {
                    //check if this number exists in the array
                    for (int i = 0; i < aList.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (aList[i] == num1)
                        {
                            //this number exists in the list
                            Console.WriteLine("{0} has already been entered", aList[i]);
                            isDuplicate = true;
                        }
                    }

                    // FIX: This should only happen if the number
                    // is not a duplicate
                    if (!isDuplicate)
                    {
                        //put the number into the array
                        aList[counter] = num1;

                        // FIX: Move this line into here to only increment 
                        // the counter if th enumber is placed in the array
                        //increment the counter
                        counter++;
                    }

                    //print the array
                    for (int j = 0; j < aList.Length; j++)
                    {
                        //exclude zeros
                        if (aList[j] == 0)
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(aList[j]);
                        }
                    }

                    //reset the flag
                    isDuplicate = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Numbers should be between 10 and 100");
                }
            }

#if DEBUG
            Console.ReadKey();
#endif

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You just saved me from writing this answer :D Also I would use `counter` instead of `aList.Length` for the both loops. In that case the *exclude zeros* `if statement` won't be necessary... I would be really shocked if this code was written by a C# instructor!!

Comment: I have a link to the video :).  Here is also an excerpt from an email response to me when I questioned some of the material and explained some of the changes I made.  "It sounds like you're just making changes to the statement without purpose. It would never be an AND statement since we want to ask "is this number between 10 and 100?". We know it's going to be a two-condition OR.
If we think about it, the statement has to be >= 10 since we don't want numbers below 10. Likewise we need to set the upper limit of <= 100 since we want numbers up to 100 but not over it."

Comment: Might be time to get a refund.  That instructor doesn't understand basic boolean logic, which doesn't bode well for the course.  Best of luck.

Comment: The "!isDuplicate" was what I missed.  I talked to an Engineer at work today and he agreed with the "&" statement but my instructor was absolutely opposed.  It made logical sense to me, but then again, I am just a student trying to learn.  Thank You!

Comment: Yeah, as I said, there are plenty of style issues here (and to be fair, many of them might be bad styles because you haven't learned better ways yet, code used in learning doesn't always look pretty), but that if check is just wrong.  Your instructor can't talk it into being right.  Feel free to tell him an anonymous developer on the Internet disagrees with him. :)